# Change text in a cell depending on date in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have used conditional formatting to change color based on the text in column H. Now I want to change the text in column H's cells depending on the date in column L. If the date is equal or later than today's date the text should change from "In life" to "Report".

I have tried numerous formulas, but it just won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A2>=TODAY(),"Report", "In Life")
```

where A2 is the date you wish to check. Note that in this example, A2 would have to be changed in each formula if checking multiple dates.

Alternately

```
 =IF(A2<TODAY(),"Protocol", IF(A2=TODAY(), "In Life", "Report"))
```

would produce "Protocol" if the date was earlier than `TODAY()`, "In Life" if the date was equal to `TODAY()`, or "Report" if the date was after `TODAY()`.

[image: Excel Formula To Select Text Based On Date]

Again, A2 would need to be changed for each formula with the correct date to check.

As a side note, if you get a long number rather than a date, make sure the cell with the formula is formatted to display dates.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! How could I add another option - if today's date is earlier than the date in A, the text should read 'Protocol'?

Comment: @Anaksunaman: why bother with the `And()` and the second condition? Instead of picking an arbitrary end-of-time, why not simply use `=IF(A2>=TODAY, "Report", "In Life")`?

Comment: @Lisa: note that "today's date is earlier than A" is the exact opposite condition as in your question, "A is equal to or later than today", so you'd simply make "Protocol" the other branch, rather than "In Life".

Comment: @outis Apparently 'cause I are a doofus when it comes to Excel and reading... derp! :-P Thanks for the heads up. ;-)

Comment: @Lisa I believe your formula would look something like =IF(A2<B1,"Protocol", IF(A2>=TODAY(), "Report", "In Life")) -- but as outis points out, this seems redundant, unless perhaps this is used for other cells. Not sure if this is helpfule but =IF(A2<B1,"Protocol", IF(A2=TODAY(), "In Life", "Report")) would produce "Protocol" for dates earlier than today, "In Life" for today's date, and "Report" for future dates assuming B1 was TODAY().